# Javascript: Convert a string representation of money to Number

Tags: javascript, number-formatting, money-format

Lets say I have an amount in string format like this:

```
amount = '12,000.00'
```

I want to convert it into a Number (Javascript) or a float.

```
parseFloat(amount) // this gives me 12 as a result
Number(amount) // this gives me NaN as a result
```

Other solution I thought was this:

```
parseFloat(amount.replace(/[,]/g, ''))
```

This works fine. But the problem here is the Locale.

This would fail when the amount is € 12000,00.
Here ',' has altogether a different meaning.

I looked around for a good solution but couldn't. I am looking for a generalized solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is not that easy, as you can't exactly know what's the delimiter for thousands and what for the decimal part

Consider "12.000.000" is it `12000.000 === 12000` or `12000000`?

But if you would set the requirement that the last delimiter is always the decimal delimiter - 
meaning if at least one delimiter is given, the **last** one **has** to be the decimal delimiter, *if the digits following, don't exceed a defined length.

Then you could try the following

### Edit

<sub>(see the [revs](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16769169/revisions) if you're interested in the old function)</sub>

I put in the ability to define the max length of digits after the last delimiter "," or "." up until it is treated as float, after that its returned as integer

```
var amounts = ["12000","12.000,00", "12,000.00", "12,000,01", "12.000.02", "12,000,001"];


formatMoney.maxDecLength = 3; //Set to Infinity o.s. to disable it

function formatMoney(a) {
    var nums = a.split(/[,\.]/);
    var ret = [nums.slice(0, nums.length - 1).join("")];
    if (nums.length < 2) return +nums[0];
    ret.push(nums[nums.length - 1]);
    return +(ret.join(nums[nums.length - 1].length < formatMoney.maxDecLength ? "." : ""));
}

for ( var i=0,j;j=amounts[i];i++)
    console.log (j + " -> " +formatMoney(j));
```

Gives the output:

```
"12000 -> 12000"
"12.000,00 -> 12000"
"12,000.00 -> 12000"
"12,000,01 -> 12000.01"
"12.000.02 -> 12000.02"
"12,000,001 -> 12000001" //as you can see after the last "," there are 3 digits and its treated as integer
```

**Another  [JSBin](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16769169/revisions)**

Answer (score 0):

You can get the local decimal delimiter in this manner:

```
1.1.toLocaleString().substr(1,1)
```

Before parse float, you could make sure the string contains nothing but numbers, possibly a minus sign, and the local decimal delimiter.

Comment: Sadly `toLocaleString` is too new and unsupported to use in real-world code - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Answer (score 0):

The truth is, you'll never know the format. `12,345`. Is that `12345`, or another locale version if `12.345`?

However, if you have consistent decimals, then you'd be able to use the [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) function on a comma and a period will reveal the decimal position and character.

```
var price = '12,345.67';
var lastPeriod = price.lastIndexOf('.');
var lastComma = price.lastIndexOf(',');
if (lastComma != -1 && lastComma > lastPeriod) {
    decimalCharacter = ',';
} else {
    decimalCharacter = '.';
}
console.log(decimalCharacter); //. or , based on how the price string looks - see below
```

If `price` is `12,345.67`, `decimalCharacter` will be `.`. If it's `12.345,67`, it'll be returned as `,`.